# Texture not showing correctly?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to display a JPG texture using OpenGL, but I have some problems. This is the important part of my code:

```
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("resources/triangle.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

The JPG file that I am trying to load can be downloaded [here](https://ufile.io/alews). It works with certain JPG files but not this one, so it is clearly something regarding the formatting - but what and why?

This is how the texture is displayed
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works with certain JPG files but not this one, so it is clearly something regarding the formatting - but what and why?

By default OpenGL assumes that the size of each row of an image is aligned 4 bytes.

This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4.

Since the image has 3 color channels (because its a JPG), and is tightly packed the size of a row of the image may not be aligned to 4 bytes. Note if the width of an image would by 4, then it would be aligned to 4 bytes, because 4 * 3 = 12 bytes. But if the width would be 5, it wouldn't be aligned to 4, because 5 * 3 = 15 bytes.

This cause that the rows of the image seems to be misplaced. Set the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to 1, to solve your issue:

```
glPixelStore( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

---

Further note, you are assuming that the image has 3 color channels, because of the `GL_RGB` format parameter in `glTexImage2D`. In this case this works, because   of the JPG file format.
`stbi_load` returns the number of color channels contained in the image buffer (`nrChannels`).
Take respect on it, by either using `GL_RGB` or `GL_RGBA` for the format parameter, somehow like that:

```
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
    nrChannels == 3 ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Comment: It worked - thanks wizard :) But how did you figure out that all that information about the JPG file? Other JPGs are different (which must be why some JPGs worked for me) - so how can you spot such things as the color channels?

Comment: @sostack As I mentioned in the answer, it depends on the width of the image. Each pixel has 3 bytes (because it's a jpg). If 3*width is divisible by 4 it works, if not it fails. You are not the 1st on who did this mistake and won't be the last one, as myself.